# How to confirm a new remote host key in Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

The exact error is "Could not establish connection to "[server_name]": Remote host key has changed, port forwarding is disabled."

I recently "rolled back" a production environment's update by launching a new instance from a back up. This gives me a new server host key, as expected. Every other SSH connection tool I've used (WinSCP, FileZilla, Text Wrangler, Putty, Terminal, DBeaver, etc) has a notification of the change and lets you confirm the key yourself and verify it is valid (or not).

I cannot find that option in VS Code remote dev tools. It prompts to simply close or retry(same error, obviously). The "More actions" option doesn't give me anything but configuration file options, settings that I believe don't allow me to update the host key, and the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) which to the best of my knowledge doesn't explain how to update the host key either.

I assume I'm missing something simple somewhere... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It was something simple. Found while trying to review the question.

"A supported OpenSSH compatible SSH client must also be installed." as listed in the system requirements of the documentation(linked in question). The key simply needs to be updated in said OpenSSH client before attempting the connection in Visual Studio again.

In this exact case it was as simple as going to [local_path]/.ssh/known_hosts and removing the old entry for the IP address and then attempting the connection again which now allows the verification of the new key.

Comment: I'd just like to add something that helped me - whenever you use VSCode to connect and you get the above error message, look in the "OUTPUT" section - you should see a message like "@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @". Underneath in the text it will tell you the path to your local known_hosts file if you do not know where it is. You then literally remove the line in the known_hosts file that corresponds to the server you're trying to connect to. Then try connecting again.

Comment: This additional comment helped a great deal in my case.

Comment: +1! If you search for `ctrl+f` and `known_hosts`, it will also give you an immediate command with `key-gen -f` keyto remove that specific line. `ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"` (being that the remote ip you are trying to connect to).

Answer (score 11):

remove the hostname's key

```
ssh-keygen -R "hostname"
```

Comment: I also had to quit VS Code and restart.

Comment: Starting a new terminal session would do